# Sound Effects on Samples in Minim

Tags: processing, minim

So I'm trying to put a Delay, Tremolo, and other effects on a audio sample in Minim.

I can easily have these effects manipulate a generated signal using the documentation, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to get the effects to work on audio samples.

Does anyone have an example or program I could use as reference? I would like to stay in minim as this is part of a larger project that uses minim for a bunch of other things.